# How to configure development and deployment database for heroku?

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, heroku

I started playing around with Heroku today. 
I'm a bit confused on how to set up my development environment vs deployment.

I'm working on a django app. Not RoR haha.

Should I use a mysql database for development and postgres for deployment? Or should I keep them both postgres? What should I keep in mind?

Are there any tricks or tips for deploying database configurations and running local tests?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either way. Either have `mysql`/`sqlite` for dev & `postgres` for prod, or have `postgres` for both. Depends on what you are comfortable with.

Only thing to ensure is to separate the related gems required for dev & prod.

Partial content of Gemfile when `mysql` is used for dev & `postgres` for prod:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.11.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'
  # gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
end
```

Comment: Ahh I see... Now what if I were to be working on a Django project and not a RoR one?

Comment: The advice about using a convenient db type in dev applies to Django as well, from what I understand from [Getting started with django on heroku page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#database-settings).

Comment: If you use a different database type locally than you do remotely, you will have a bad time, eventually. Better to start of with parity and keep it, rather than switch when you get bit.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you should try and use the same database for development as you do for production. They are not necessarily interchangeable. However, I have been known to ignore this rule myself due to the pure convenience of sqlite ;)

Answer (score 1):

Heroku recommends using the same setup locally as much as possible: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup

As much as ORMs abstract much of the details away, it's still a good idea to have dev/production parity, and will help when you want to download a pg_dump of your production app for use locally.